# Perl: Find line with matching string(str1) and only in those matched lines, replace one string(str2) with specific string(str3)

Tags: regex, perl

I have one file a.txt with contents as follow:

```
a aa aaa
b bb value = 11 xyz
c cc ccc
b bb value = 222 abc
d dd ddd
```

I have to find for string "bb". once matching line found i have to replace "value = xxx" with "value = 77"
Here, xxx is integer with any number of digit(11,222 in above case).

I have tried below perl command:

```
perl -n -e 'print; if (m/\bbb\b/) { s/value = (\d+)/value = 77/g; print; }' < a.txt
```

It gives me output as:

```
a aa aaa
b bb value = 11 xyz
b bb value = 77 xyz
c cc ccc
b bb value = 22 abc
b bb value = 77 abc
d dd ddd
```

Here i am looking for in-place replacement, instead of new line with required changes.
Basically i am expecting output as follow:

```
a aa aaa
b bb value = 77 xyz
c cc ccc
b bb value = 77 abc
d dd ddd
```

Can anyone help me here in updating my command?

Also one more quick question, can I update my above command in way so that it can search for string "bb" and only matching lines will remove the string "value = xxx" completely from this matching line.
where xxx is integer with any number of digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You print twice when you have a match. If you don't want to do that, don't do that :)

```
perl -n -e 'if (m/\bbb\b/) { s/value = (\d+)/value = 77/g; } print' < a.txt
```

Cleaned up:

```
perl -pe's/value = \K\d+/77/g if /\bbb\b/' a.txt
```

Based on the sample data, you might even be able to use

```
perl -pe's/\bbb\b.*value = \K\d+/77/' a.txt
```

Comment: This looks simple. Any idea about my second query, mentioned at the end of question.

Comment: `s/value = \d+//`

Comment: Thanks @ikegami, below command works for me: perl -pe's/value = \d+// if /\bbb\b/' a.txt

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
perl -n -e 'if (m/\bbb\b/) { s/value = (\d+)/value = 77/g; print; } else {print}' < a.txt
```

put one print in `if` and one in `else`

Output:

```
$ perl -n -e 'if (m/\bbb\b/) { s/value = (\d+)/value = 77/g; print; } else {print}' < a.txt
a aa aaa
b bb value = 77 xyz
c cc ccc
b bb value = 77 abc
d dd ddd
```

Comment: Thanks @Jens for your help. This works for my replacement scenario. Any idea about my second query: Can I update my command in way so that it can search for string "bb" and only matching lines will remove the string "value = xxx"  from this matching line. where xxx is integer with any number of digit. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SatishKale can you give me some example?

Comment: lets say in above file a.txt, i have to find lines with "bb" string... so i will get line "b bb value = 11 xyz "` and in this line i have to delete string "value = 11" so that finally line will be " b bb xyz "

Comment: below command works for me for second query: perl -pe's/value = \d+// if /\bbb\b/' a.txt